Motivating pure functions: are all pure functions commutative in execution order?
I’m trying to understand whether all pure functions are commutative with respect to execution order. That is, does the order in which pure functions are executed ever matter, assuming no external state is modified?
I haven't seen "commutative" and "pure functions" put together in the way I wanted (i.e. in execution order) in any of my searches.
Non-example: Not in a functional context
In this case, mutation of x prevents commutativity:
fn foo() -> 2 // always returns 2
fn bar() -> 3 // always returns 3

x = foo();
x = bar(); // x is mutated

// Switching lines gives different results, so this is not commutative:
x = bar();
x = foo();

Here, x is mutated, violating the functional paradigm. The order of operations matters because x gets reassigned.
Example: Pure functions are commutative
In the following example, no mutation occurs, so the execution order can be swapped without changing the result:
x = foo(); // x = 2
y = bar(); // y = 3

// Equivalent even if the order is reversed:
y = bar(); // y = 3
x = foo(); // x = 2

Since the functions foo() and bar() are pure, the order of execution does not matter.
Example: Side effects disable commutativity
If a function modifies external state, it is no longer pure, and execution order does matter:
fn foo() -> print("Hello") // modifies external state
fn bar() -> print("Hi")

foo(); // writes "Hello"
bar(); // writes "Hi"

bar(); // writes "Hi"
foo(); // writes "Hello"

Here, since the functions foo() and bar() have side effects (printing to the console), the order of execution does matter.
If both foo() and bar() are pure (i.e., they don’t modify external state), then switching their execution order should not affect the result. This is similar to how pure functions are often run in parallel, as mentioned in this guide.

My Question
Can we always assume that pure functions are commutative with respect to execution order?
I instinctively think yes, but I’d like to clarify this further and see if there are exceptions. Is there any scenario where pure functions cannot be commuted? I would appreciate any clarification from a more experienced perspective.

The identity monad is of course commutative if that's what you're asking.

Do you instinctively think "yes, we can always assume that pure functions are commutative", or "yes, there is any scenario where pure functions cannot be commuted"?

@NaïmFavier I've been scared by that word before (and potentially still am), but the explanation seems pretty straightforward. I don't know much theory, but I think I could take that as an answer.

Yes and no.
As (among others) Simon Peyton Jones has remarked, a pure function is itself useless. You can't observe that it ran, or what the output is.
Take pure functions in Haskell as an example. Haskell is a lazily evaluated language, so functions are only evaluated if some other part of the program needs the return value. Ultimately, the only way a program can need a value is if it wants to do something with it. That includes writing it to the console, sending it in an email, writing it to a file, etc.
In isolation, a pure function that remains unused is fair game for the compiler to optimize away. Take a simple example:
myFunction x y =
  let ignored = 2 + 2
  in x + y

The value ignored is the result of the pure function +, but since the variable is never used, the compiler will typically erase it.
The same may happen to myFunction. Only if you (transitively) use myFunction in some impure part of your program will it even be evaluated.
Once you use it for something that has a side effect, the order will typically matter, unless you're truly working with a commutative operation (such as +).
Theoretically, you may think of pure functions as commutative, because if never evaluated, they're morally equivalent to unit ('nothing', 'no-op'). And unit is commutative. Two 'nothings' make one 'nothing', and it doesn't matter how you order them, because there's universally only one 'nothing' value.
Practically, pure functions can't be assumed to be commutative, because the order in which you operate on them typically matter.
Yes, you can still run pure functions in parallel if they're independent, but the order in which you compose the result still matter.
Imagine parallelizing operations on a long string or sequence of values. Once each parallel process is done with its part, you can concatenate the parts together to a single sequence. The order of concatenation still matters, since concatenation is associative, but not commutative. As an example, if one thread computed the (partial) result "foo" and another thread the result "bar", it matters whether you concatenate the results as "foobar" or "barfoo".

I guess pure functions are impractical until something happens to them. Anyway, I was asking this question for functional programs so I can impose the condition of no mutation, but you presented concatenation as a counterexample, which is mutation in your context: let me explain. Avoiding mutation must mean a predefined order by which concatenation can occur (let x = foo() + bar()). Although I'm not sure this applies to all cases, I feel that uncertainty in order can only arise if threads append to a shared value, initially an empty string. That is mutation, and therefore not functional.

I think you were trying to refer to something like this:
let base = "";

thread1: base += "foo";
thread2: base += "bar";

However, that is mutation, which is what I was trying to describe in the previous comment. I can't think of any other counterexample of commutativity failing in functional contexts. Other than that, I'm pretty convinced by the "two nothings are commutative" "proof".

I think OP is referring to commutativity of evaluation order, not of the order of arguments that are passed to another function. The question is not whether foo() ++ bar() is the same as bar() ++ foo(), but whether let a = foo() in let b = bar() in a ++ b is the same as let b = bar() in let a = foo() in a ++ b (assuming eager evaluation and a non-commutative ++, such as concatenation).

@Bergi Yes, when presented like that, it looks as though you could say that order of evaluation is commutative.
